# Send a file to OpenAI API without accessing the file system

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, stream, openai-api

How can I send a file to the OpenAI API without accessing the file system? I have the file contents as a string. The provided code in the OpenAI documentation reads a file from the file system, but I want to avoid that step.

Docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files/upload

I tried this

```
const readableStream = Readable.from(fileContents);
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can create a blob from your string data and then use `new File()` to create a File object that Open AI will accept.

```
// Create a blob from your fileContents string
const blob = new Blob([fileContents], { type: 'text/plain' });

// Set your desired filename and MIME type
const fileName = 'example.txt';
const fileMime = 'text/plain';

// Create your File object
const file = new File([blob], fileName, { type: fileMime }); 

// Upload your file to Open AI
const upload = await openai.files.create({
  file: file,
  purpose: "assistants",
})
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually work. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: @bynary Yes it is the solution I found to work for me

Comment: This is one of the supported ways as mentioned in openai-node README https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/master/README.md#file-uploads

Be aware that `File` class is available since node 20 (was experimental since node 18) https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#class-file